# Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS sudo apt-get update exits with dpkg error code (1)

Tags: apt, ubuntu, update, sudo, dpkg

I'm running a Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS xenial. `sudo apt-get update` exits with:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.157.11_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin', which is also in package linux-firmware-raspi2 1.20161020-0ubuntu1~0.2~rpi3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

...

Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.157.11_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The bulk of my search results for this problem are for the dreaded locked file or networking issues.

`sudo apt-get install -f` didn't help.

Would my question be better served on Ask Ubuntu?

If so should I leave it up here and cross post it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally, brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin was provided by linux-firmware-raspi2 package from ppa.
But recent linux-firmware package from ubuntu also provides the same file.

dpkg-divert solution is works for me.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware-raspi2/+bug/1691729/comments/4

> sudo dpkg-divert --divert /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio-2.bin --package linux-firmware-raspi2 --rename --add /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin

References: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware-raspi2/+bug/1691729

Comment: dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio-2.bin' with
  different file '/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin', not allowed

dpkg-divert rejects that command