# How do I install ubuntu server 16.04 on pi3 model B

Tags: boot, boot-issues, server, ubuntu, operating-systems

I have tried the instructions at [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi), especially the ones under

> Booting the official Pi 2 image on the Pi 3

I downloaded both pre-installed server versions *armhf+raspi2* and *armhf+raspi3*. I made the changes to `config.txt` in the boot-loader partition and copied the files over from `/lib/firmware/4.4.0-1065-raspi2/device-tree` to the system-boot partition.

When I try to boot, a static colorful screen is shown and nothing else happens, no matter how much I wait.

I've been reading around that there are problems with the distribution of Ubuntu server on Raspberry Pi even from the the Pi2 days.

Has anyone managed to install Ubuntu Server on the Raspberry Pi with today's information and links?

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu Mate as a headless server? Remembering not to update by CLI though.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried to use raspi2 image, but know some pitfalls about raspi3 image:

1. dd raspi3 image to MicroSD
2. boot (DO NOT reboot before `apt upgrade` complete)
3. apt update, apt upgrade

   - apt upgrade will fail on dpkg error. Need to setup diversion. [Raspberry Pi 3 with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS sudo apt-get update exits with dpkg error code (1)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/71059/raspberry-pi-3-with-ubuntu-16-04-3-lts-sudo-apt-get-update-exits-with-dpkg-error)
4. reboot

   - bootloader will fail to find a device tree. Need to edit config.txt: [Raspberry Pi 3 Ubuntu 16.04 Server upgrade error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61342/raspberry-pi-3-ubuntu-16-04-server-upgrade-error/62384)
5. :-)